# c# Should I store a copy of a field for convenience?

Tags: c#

I have developed a habit of sometimes doing this particular thing and I'm wondering why am I doing it, is there any advantage?

Heres an example from a Unity3d game..
In my class I want to do various calculations and so forth with a float ThingYposition which is a field stored somewhere in Thing.transform.position.y. Rather than be writing Thing.transform.position.y so many times I just make a  copy of the float I want at the beginning of the program.

```
public GameObject Thing; 
private float ThingYposition;

public Start()
{
    ThingYposition = Thing.transform.position.y
}

public Update()
{
    //Do stuff every frame with ThingYposition
}
```

So this way means my lines of code will be a little less cluttered but the program will use a little bit more memory as I'm storing that float twice now. But will it be any faster? Does accessing a deeply embedded field like Thing.transform.position.y actually use any more processing power than accessing my float field? 
Do you think this is harmless habit or should I stop?

Also please note in this example I dont care if the original changes at all and I dont want to change it.

Comment: This should be asked on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: See also the [Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you don't care whether or not the original position changes and will not change it yourself, then this is probably the best approach for the use-case you described.

The answer to the other part of your question, is it faster to access a local vs a "deeply embedded field" depends on how `Thing.transform.position.y` is implemented.  If it just a member field, then the access times would be essentially the same for a local copy or the "deeply embedded field".  If `Thing.transform.position.y` is calculated on every access then the local copy would be faster.

Answer (score 1):

You already stated you don't care if the original changes, so I'll skip that part. The only advantage I can see is in a multi-threaded environment. You don't have to worry about another thread mucking with `Thing`, since you have a private copy of `ThingYposition`.

In terms of efficiency, you're well into micro optimizing here. If you're having a problem, profile it and experiment with alternatives. But I can't imagine this is something you really need to worry about.